# Words I added to the personal dictionary are ignored

Tags: editing, dictionaries

I added words to the dictionary but sigil continues to underline them with red in the editors. I closed and reopened the program (like a restart), but to no avail. There are no complicated instructions to follow, simply open Preferences, add words, hit OK, and close. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks so much.[image]